# Cakephp compare created day with today date

Tags: cakephp

I have problem with comparison of dates in cakephp because I have to compare ONLY date of my field (order.created (datetime format in mysql) with today date in query, also in row "conditions" I was trying .. but..

```
$this->paginate = array(
            'limit' => 20,
            'order' => 'Order.id DESC',
            **'conditions' => array($this->Time->isToday('Order.created'))**,
            'fields' => array('Order.*', 'User.name'),
            'joins' => array(
                array(
                    'table' => 'users',
                    'alias' => 'User',
                    'type' => 'left',
                    'conditions' => array('User.id = Order.user_id')
                )
            )
        );
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
'conditions' => array('DATE(Order.created)' => date('Y-m-d'))
```

Using MySQL `DATE()` you need to convert `created` to `YYYY-MM-DD` format, because usually it's `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`.

Answer (score 0):

```
'conditions' => array('Order.created' => date('Y-m-d'))
```

Comment: not working.. maybe problem is that, because my type of field 'created' is datetime not only date.? what are you thnik?